# how to connect nodes on different machines?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have two signing nodes on machine #1 and two new nodes on machine #2.

The nodes on #1 are running and I have them in admin under geth. But when I try and connect the nodes on #2 I get various errors. I think this is IP related. I did ifconfig on #1 and used the broadcast address.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and geth 1.8. The nodes on #1 seem to work. I use PoA and the network is private.

Has anyone any idea what could be the cause?

From #2 Connection Request -

> geth --datadir node3/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30313 --rpc --rpcaddr
>   'localhost' --rpcport 8503 --rpcapi 'p
>   ersonal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner ' --bootnodes
>   'enode://601ade737b81f16abdd0ce9983b63eb12050c4ef89c46b8fdbf3e3e6c951cc02dffe36f87200033107cf
>   8b007355e780fba16b67d1d46603b1321f07 314ea46b@10.132.0.2:30310'
>   --networkid 1515 --gasprice '1' -unlock 'afd3cfddc8f5ed78ea9bbbf6c13d3dc40be4541 7' --password
>   node3/pwdnode3.txt --mine

Error on #2 -

> ERROR[04-14|12:20:43] Bootstrap URL invalid
>   enode="enode://601ade737b81f16abdd0ce9983b63eb12050c4ef89c46b8fdbf3e3e6c951cc02dffe36f87200033107cf8b007355e780fba16b67d1d46603b1321f07\n314ea46b@10.132.0.2:30310"
>   err="parse
>   enode://601ade737b81f16abdd0ce9983b63eb12050c4ef89c46b8fdbf3e3e6c951cc02dffe36f87200033107cf8b007355e780fba16b67d1d46603b1321f07\n314ea46b@10.132.0.2:30310:
>   net/url: invalid userinfo"

From #1

```
admin.nodeInfo
```

> {   enode:
>   "enode://64793e6e791115d315550d651cda00342b688ba36728b3d8070b04f4513ff65eb15ffb8f66387f1733340d8732e6ca956f0825cd3fc4e67686e04f63c5d0abc4@[::]:30311",
>   id:
>   "64793e6e791115d315550d651cda00342b688ba36728b3d8070b04f4513ff65eb15ffb8f66387f1733340d8732e6ca956f0825cd3fc4e67686e04f63c5d0abc4",
>   ip: "::",   listenAddr: "[::]:30311",   name:
>   "Geth/v1.8.2-stable-b8b9f7f4/linux-amd64/go1.9.4",   ports: {
>       discovery: 30311,
>       listener: 30311   },   protocols: {
>       eth: {
>         config: {
>           byzantiumBlock: 4,
>           chainId: 1515,
>           clique: {...},
>           eip150Block: 2,
>           eip150Hash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>           eip155Block: 3,
>           eip158Block: 3,
>           homesteadBlock: 1
>         },
>         difficulty: 10593,
>         genesis: "0x702d8ca9647d171a6596a775888f71c7c0f3ddb011fbffcb921be685b2ef33b7",
>         head: "0x1a8f2a0bf37fbabff2c76977cbfa56c67da056025292fad6bbd5da07d2d0af28",
>         network: 1515
>       }   } }

This is how I connect on #1 and that works -

> geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --rpc --rpcaddr
>   'loca lhost' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi
>   'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnod es
>   'enode://601ade737b81f16abdd0ce9983b63eb12050c4ef89c46b8fdbf3e3e6c951cc02dffe
>   36f87200033107cf8b007355e780fba16b67d1d46603b1321f07314ea46b@127.0.0.1:30310'
>   -- networkid 1515 --gasprice '1' -unlock 'fcad53c780a4f6c66b3daca331fe72fc6559c367'  --password
>   node1/pwdnode1.txt --mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space in your nodeid -> `...f07 314...`